# Can I select the price to be returned in another currency?

Tags: amadeus

I am using the Amadeus Python Client and the results are being returned in Euros. Is there any way to get the results in US Dollars?

I looked at the documentation but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the Flight Offers Search API, the parameter `currencyCode` specifies the preferred currency. Currency is specified in the ISO 4217 format, e.g. EUR for Euro. More information can be found in the [API reference](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference).